# I cannot get a Restcontroller included in Spring Boot project - error 404

Tags: spring, spring-boot

newbie pb on Spring Boot, I cannot get a RestController to be added to my application.

Here are the 2 files used to build this very simple app with maven:

**1) Application.java**

```
package com.learn.hello;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.learn.hello.controller")
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
    return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
}
}
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.learn.hello.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping("/titi")
public String index() {
    return "Greetings from titi Boot!";
}

}
```

Structure of the project

```
/src/main/java/com/learn/hello/Application.java
/src/main/java/com/learn/hello/controller/HelloController.java
/target/*
/pom.xml
```

localhost:8080 works

but localhost:8080/titi does not (404 not found)

Any idea ?
Thx

Comment: Can you show your startup logs?

Comment: You forgot to provide request method RequestMethod.GET :

@RequestMapping(value = "/students", method = RequestMethod.GET)


You can use @GetMapping("/titi") instead @RequestMapping("/titi")

Comment: remove @restcontroller and ComponentScan from class Application

Comment: it is so strange all seems to be ok, the only hint that I can do is remove the @ ComponentScan because the controller it is already included by   @ SpringBootApplication that already perform a @ ComponentScan of /Application.java
/src/main/java/com/**

Comment: repeate it is so stange I test the same your clases and in my loacal environment its work! perapsh your problem is in on other place please share more details about your project

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to provide request method RequestMethod.GET :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/students", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

You can use @GetMapping("/titi") instead of @RequestMapping("/titi") :

```
@GetMapping("/titi")
```

Answer (score 0):

To all, thanks a lot to all for your answers.

@Valerio,
you were right it was correct!!! In fact an invisible char got added at the end of the filename: HelloController.java (me probably messing-up with Sublime...), thus it was not processed as a java file by maven...

Sorry for the noise.My apologies.

BTW if anybody knows about any sort of options to actually warn that a file located in the /src/main/java/* directories was not processed as a "regular java project" file I'm interested to know about it even though I doubt that this is really feasible and thus existing...